# How can I copy this function but with preset values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Currently when a button is clicked, it subtracts an inputted value. I want to have a preset value subtracted once a preset button is clicked. It would also be perferable that I could reuse a function later on a different button with different values like so:

```
var preset = function(val1, val2, val3, val4) {
    //function to subtract from current values
}
$('presetButton').click(function(){
    preset(1,2,3,4)
}
```

Here is the current function as I have it. The first button function works, but I wanted to copy it into a preset button with preset values. The function would not include $(this) because the button would not be in the same wrapper div and are not siblings.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('button').click(function(){
        var $button = $(this);
        var subtract = parseInt($button.siblings('input').val(), 10);
        var $currentP = $button.siblings('.number').children('p');
        var current = parseInt($currentP.text(), 10);
        var newVal = current - subtract;
        var $history = $button.siblings('.wrap').children('.history');
       if (isNaN(subtract)) {
        alert("Please enter in a number");
       } else {
            $currentP.effect('bounce', function() {
              $currentP.text(newVal);
              $(this).show();
          });
            $history.append("<p>"+subtract+"</p>");
       }
    });
    $('#presets').click(function(){
        //set up the subtracting and current variables
        var subCal = 120;
        var subPro = 24;
        var subCarbs = 3;
        var subFat = 1;

        //retrieve current number then convert to a number
        var toNum = function(id) {
            return parseInt($(id + ' .number').children('p').text(), 10);
        }
        var curCal = toNum('#calories');
        var curPro = toNum('#protein');
        var curCarbs = toNum('#carbs');
        var curFat = toNum('#fats');

        //create new values
        var newCal = curCal - subCal;
        var newPro = curPro - subPro;
        var newCarbs = curCarbs - subCarbs;
        var newFat = curFat - subFat;

        //apply new values
        var applyNew = function(id, newVal) {
            $(id + ' .number p').text(newVal)
        }
        applyNew('#calories', newCal);
        applyNew('#protein', newPro);
        applyNew('#carbs', newCarbs);
        applyNew('#fats', newFats);

            //Add to presets to history
    })
});
```

The HTML

```
<h1>Track your Macros</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="calories">
            <div class="number"><p>1945</p></div>
            <div class="label"><p>Calories</p></div>
            <input type="text"></input>
            <button>Subtract</button>
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="history"></div>
            </div>


        </div>
        <div id="protein">
            <div class="number"><p>200</p></div>
            <div class="label"><p>Protein</p></div>
            <input type="text"></input>
            <button>Subtract</button>
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="history"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="carbs">
            <div class="number"><p>173</p></div>
            <div class="label"><p>Carbs</p></div>
            <input type="text" class="subtract"></input>
            <button>Subtract</button>
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="history"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="fats">
            <div class="number"><p>50</p></div>
            <div class="label"><p>Fats</p></div>
            <input type="text" class="subtract"></input>
            <button>Subtract</button>
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="history"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="presets"><img src="on-logo.png"></div>
```

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SSV9s/1/

Comment: It works, but could you tell me what you changed. I see you added a space in ' .number p' and put #calories in '', but the other changes I'm not sure what they are. 

Also how could I add the presets into the history like I had it in the original button function?

Comment: nvm i got it working, but I still need to work on the history part.

Comment: what changes did you make

Comment: Before it was id +'.number p' changed it to id + ' .number p' Then I changed the ids from #calories to '#calories' for all of them. It worked then.

Comment: what I was asking was other than what I made, did you make any other changes... if not I'll post it as an answer

Comment: I have not changed anything else. An answer for the history part would be great.

Comment: I didn't get the history part... what do you want to do

Comment: currently when the button is clicked, the inputted value is subtracted from .number p. The subtracted value is appended into a <p> in the .history div. The preset would have to do the same but with the preset values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('button').click(function(){
        var $button = $(this);
        var subtract = parseInt($button.siblings('input').val(), 10);
        var $currentP = $button.siblings('.number').children('p');
        var current = parseInt($currentP.text(), 10);
        var newVal = current - subtract;
        var $history = $button.siblings('.wrap').children('.history');
        if (isNaN(subtract)) {
            alert("Please enter in a number");
        } else {
            $currentP.effect('bounce', function() {
                $currentP.text(newVal);
                $(this).show();
            });
            $history.append("<p>"+subtract+"</p>");
        }
    });
    var preset = function(val1, val2, val3, val4) {
        //set up the subtracting and current variables
        var subCal = val1;
        var subPro = val2;
        var subCarbs = val3;
        var subFat = val4;

        //retrieve current number then convert to a number
        var toNum = function(id) {
            return parseInt($(id + ' .number').children('p').text(), 10);
        }
        var curCal = toNum('#calories');
        var curPro = toNum('#protein');
        var curCarbs = toNum('#carbs');
        var curFat = toNum('#fats');

        //create new values
        var newCal = curCal - subCal;
        var newPro = curPro - subPro;
        var newCarbs = curCarbs - subCarbs;
        var newFats = curFat - subFat;

        //apply new values
        var applyNew = function(id, newVal) {
            $(id + ' .number p').text(newVal);
        }
        //apply new values
        var applyHistory = function(id, val) {
            $(id + ' .history').append("<p>" + val + "</p>");
        }

        applyNew('#calories', newCal);
        applyNew('#protein', newPro);
        applyNew('#carbs', newCarbs);
        applyNew('#fats', newFats);

        applyHistory('#calories', subCal);
        applyHistory('#protein', subPro);
        applyHistory('#carbs', subCarbs);
        applyHistory('#fats', subFat);
    }
    $('#presets').click(function(){
        preset(120,24,3,1);
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SSV9s/)

Comment: If I wanted to make a more generic function could I copy this into a preset() function where the parameters are replace subCal, subPro, subCarbs, subFats?